# Outlook can't recognize "Sent" and "Trash" path on IMAP account

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, imap

**I have Outlook from Office365** and I can't set correctly some folders, to be synchronized between webmail and the Outlook. Let's say that the default path on my server looks as follows:

- Sent
- Trash
- Drafts
- Spam

But Outlook recognize correctly only the last two, and for the first two creates its own folders:

- Sent items
- Deleted items
- Drafts
- Spam

So only half of my folders is synchronized correctly. For Sent/Trash I have everything split between different localizations depending of device I use - my browser, and mobile phone use the second option, the Outlook use the first. It's doing a mess in my mail box. How to force Outlook to use correct folder names, instead of creating its own? I was trying to remove and add account multiple times - every time "Sent items" and "Deleted items" are recreated.

I've read other similar questions but no one provided solution which would work for new Outlook from Office365, there are answers for Office 2010, which are not longer applicable in newer versions.

Answer (score 1):

Could you also find those folders(Sent and Trash) in your Outlook desktop client? And have you configured the root folder path?

Based on my research, Outlook may not always recognize the correct folders when the IMAP mailbox is based on a “root structure” where all the other mail folders are created under the default Inbox folder, which may cause Outlook ignores the already existing Sent Items and Deleted Items folder on the server and create some local ones of its own. Please kindly check it(File>Account settings>Account Settings>choose your account> Root folder path).

If your "Sent & Trash" folder is under Inbox label, you could try to set the root to "Inbox" to check if the issue has any difference.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Ok, I tested this, and when I set root folder to Inbox, I see only Inbox, all other folders are not available. So also draft or spam folder disappear, it's even worse than leaving root folder empty.

Comment: Please understand the setting of  "Inbox" is used for your "your "Sent & Trash" folder is under Inbox label". The specific setting depend on your structure of folders. In order to further confirm your stucture of folder, please find it via Folder>IMAP Folder>Query and check if your Sent&Trash is under any label.

Comment: I'm not sure if you are referring to the latest version of Outlook. In 2019/office365 version, no label are visible if you search in IMAP folder. At least I can't find any labels, even for inbox. Can you provide more details? Maybe a screenshot so I will be sure we are talking about the same option.

Comment: I have updated my answer above with  folder picture, please kindly check it. Actually, as the screenshoot showing, my spam and sent folder is under [Gmail] label(folder), please check your folder stucture as mentioned above.

Comment: OK, thank you. So the answer is: No. I don't have any prefixes (like your "[Gmail]") in this IMAP folders for any of mentioned: Sent, Draft, Trash, Spam. I also don't see any options to set it. But it seems that all this folders doesn't have any root above them. What should I do?

Comment: Thanks for your updating, I'm still researching for your issues but haven't found the specific reasons that may cause it. As an alternative, maybe you could try to move those sent messages  to the Sent folder via rules in Outlook client for your current normal use.

Answer (score 1):

In January 2023, the correct answer is that the root folder path for the gmail account in outlook needs to be set to "[Google Mail]" (make sure to copy/paste EXACTLY what's between the quotation marks. I have spent hours on this and tried "Inbox" and "Gmail" (and whatnot) and while these settings might have worked in the past, they no longer do (for me).

For the future, when the above solution does not work anymore, then remove the root folder path setting in Outlook for your gmail account entirely and resync the inbox contents with in Outlook. Outlook will now download folders that it can see and the system folders (like Sent, Bin, etc) will be placed in some root folder. This root fodler is as of Jan'23 called "[Google Mail]". Use whatever your Outlook calls this folder as root folder path setting.